# keyword choice - broad or exact?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

**Scenario:** I have two keywords "Keyword one" has larger Exact search volume then "keyword two" but "keyword two" has larger Broad search volume then keyword one.

**Exact:** "Keyword one" > "Keyword two"

**Broad:** "Keyword two" > "Keyword one"

Which keyword should i choose and why?

**Not considering the keyword competition**

Answer (score 1):

Broad match term volumes are JUNK!!!!

lets say the term "golf clubs" has 1 million broad match

this could/would include any words with "golf clubs"

new golf clubs,
used golf clubs,
old golf clubs,
rare golf clubs,
vintage golf clubs,
store golf clubs,
shop golf clubs,
ping golf clubs,
callawaygolf clubs,
bag golf clubs,
sell golf clubs,
buy golf clubs,
golf clubs tips,
red golf clubs,
ladies golf clubs,
lost golf clubs,

ect ect....it would include any search that had golf club as part of it

but exact match search volumes represent the term you type in...no more....no less!

USE EXACT for everything!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no a real answer to your question also because your asking to not consider the competitors. It depeneds on your needs and what are these keywords. For example, if there's a little intersection between those keywords, you could consider to create a landing page for both. Instead if the keywords are very similar, i will give more attention to the broad one. But also in this case it depends if the landing website is a "famous" (trusted and trafficked) one or it is a start-up website.
Hope this can help you and answer the question.